# Retain menu bar when linking to another page with ATVjs

Tags: tvos, tvml

I'm working on a simple apple tv application using the [atvjs](https://github.com/emadalam/atvjs) framework, however I am running into difficulties with the menu bar.

Does anyone know if it is possible to retain the top menu bar when navigating between pages with the 'data-href-page' attribute?

The sample code below will correctly navigate to and render the page but the menu bar is gone and requires the user to back out instead.

```
<document>
<alertTemplate>
    <title>Example for creating links to other pages</title>
    <description>Select an option</description>
    <button data-href-page="homepage">
        <text>Go To Homepage</text>
    </button>
    <button data-href-page="login" data-href-page-options='{"username": "emadalam", "password": "123456"}'>
        <text>Login</text>
    </button>
</alertTemplate>
```

Comment: I've also been curious about this. Would love to hear a solution